Цикл в потоке asyncio с возможностью остановки
Нужно запускать цикл по нажатию Shift + 1 и останавливать по Shift + 2. Всё работает, кроме как Shift + 2 после запуска. То есть цикл блокирует дальнейшее исполнение. Как это исправить?
import asyncio
from pynput import keyboard
status = False

async def my_loop():  # цикл
    global status
    while status:
        print('Testing')
        await asyncio.sleep(8)

def my_loop_start():
    global status
    status = True
    asyncio.run(my_loop())  # пуск цикла

def my_loop_stop():
    global status
    status = False

with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({'<shift>+1': my_loop_start, '<shift>+2': my_loop_stop}) as hotkeys:
    hotkeys.join()


Ваш my_loop_start блокирует основной поток, так что не удивительно, что  программа не отрабатывает на Shift + 2 ‍♀️
Вот хорошая статья, на основе которой я подкорректировал ваш код:
import asyncio
from pynput import keyboard
import threading

status = False
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
future = None

async def my_loop():  
    count = 0  
    while status:
        print('Testing')
        count += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return count # Тут мне захотелось вернуть результат, но это не обязательно.

def my_loop_start():
    global status, future
    if not status:  
        status = True
        future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(my_loop(), loop)  
        
def my_loop_stop():
    global status
    status = False
    print(future.result())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = threading.Thread(target=loop.run_forever)
    thread.start()

    with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({'<shift>+1': my_loop_start, '<shift>+2': my_loop_stop}) as hotkeys:
        hotkeys.join()

Вывод:
Testing
Testing
Testing
Testing
4

